# set a boolean variable basis on multiple key check on a map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map in which these three keys will be present:

```
Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();
holder.put("abc", "qwer");
holder.put("pqr", "dsds");
holder.put("def", "jghghg");
// data for some other keys
```

Here is what I need to do:

- If key `abc` and `pqr` both are not present and only `def` key is present then I want to assign true to a boolean variable other I will set as false.

So I did something like this but it doesn't work. Looks like my logic is wrong somehow.

```
boolean flag = !(holder.containsKey("abc") || holder.containsKey("pqr"));
```

Comment: Where is the **both** part? Also your description says "**and**", but your code "`||`" ("or").

Comment: Just replace `||` with `&&` as you want **both** of these to not to be present!

Comment: @PM77-1: `!(a || b) == (!a && !b)`

Comment: @MartinR - Yes, I know.  Where did you actually see `! (...||...)`?

Comment: @PM77-1: In `!(holder.containsKey("abc") || holder.containsKey("pqr"))` ...

Comment: What does *"something like this"* mean and how does it *"not work"*? Why does your code not involve the "def" key? Can you provide a concrete example with actual and  expected output?

Comment: @PM77-1: Strange, it compiles for me.

Comment: @MartinR - Sorry, need stronger glasses.

Comment: My eyes don't see any syntax errors there.. nice catch about where the 'missing And' is using De Morgan's law @MartinR

Comment: oops this was basic thing.. I thought I had that missing part but I didn't.. need to sleep now... sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal translation from what you wanted it to do. 
NOT-contains 'abc' AND NOT-contains 'pqr' AND contains 'def'

```
!holder.containsKey("abc") && !holder.containsKey("pqr") && holder.containsKey("def")
```

Comment: @user2004685 - It's OK by my and SO standards.